# Rails 7 How do I allow the user to create a new instance of a question from their given poll?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

I have a poll and a poll has questions. These are the models:

```
class poll < ApplicationRecord
  validates_presence_of :user, :title, :URL, :poll_type, :start_date, :end_date
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
end

class Question < ApplicationRecord
  validates_presence_of :poll_id, :question_type, :title
  belongs_to :poll
end
```

The schema for polls is as follows

```
create_table "polls", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.string "title"
    t.text "description"
    t.text "URL"
    t.string "poll_type"
    t.datetime "start_date"
    t.datetime "end_date"
    t.boolean "weighted_voting"
    t.boolean "show_results"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_polls_on_user_id"
  end
```

The schema for quesitons

```
create_table "questions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "poll_id", null: false
    t.string "question_type"
    t.string "title"
    t.text "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["ballot_id"], name: "index_questions_on_ballot_id"
  end
```

my routes.rb

```
resources :users do
    resources :polls do
      resources :questions do
        resources :options
      end
    end
  end
```

How can the user create a new instance of a question from their assigned given poll?

Currently the field poll_id in the questions form is empty. I can't figure out how to get this id populate. the polls form gets the user_id from devise's current_user.id variable via a form.

Also is doing this via the form the rails correct way of doing it?

---

Bonus Question: Would the method be the same for the options model?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by nested forms.
Details are [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for)

Firstly you should create new pool form. Basically this form must include Poll and Question form fields. You must use fields_for helper to create related forms for specific model.

### poll form

```
  <%= form_for @poll do |poll| %>
      Poll name: <%= poll.text_field :poll_name%>
   
    
      <%= fields_for :question, @poll.questions do |question_fields| %>
            Question 1  : <%= question_fields.text_field :question_1 %>
            Answer 1    : <%= question_fields.check_box :answer_1 %>
            Answer 2    : <%= question_fields.check_box :answer_2 %>
            Answer 3    : <%= question_fields.check_box :answer_3 %>
      <% end %>
    
      <%= poll.submit %>
    <% end %>
```

#### in model file

```
class Poll < ApplicationRecord
  validates_presence_of :user, :title, :URL, :poll_type, :start_date, :end_date
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
end
```

#### in poll controller permit the question attributes

```
questions_attributes: [
          :id,
          :question_text,
          :answer_1,
          :answer_2,
          ...
          :poll_id]
```

### poll controller new action

```
5.times { @poll.questions.build }
```

### info about routes

*Rails docs says: Resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep.*

You can solve your problem with only

```
resources :polls
```

All you need to do inject current_user to poll controller when saving form. You don't need to another resources for questions. You can show all questions under the poll show page.